# Excel VBA Named Range in VLOOKUP #VALUE error

Tags: vba, excel

This code throws a #VALUE error in cell A8 or A17 (depending on which toggle is active) instead of the string value from the 'dataWeaponField' named range. This Excel formula in (for example) cell A17 works correctly: =VLOOKUP(B17,dataWeaponField,2,FALSE). I am trying to simply replicate this formula in VBA.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    If Target.Column = 1 And Target.Row = 7 Then 'CLICK TO SWAP WEAPONS
        If Range("A8").Interior.ColorIndex = 6 Then 'Primary Weapon
            Range("A8:C15").Interior.ColorIndex = 12 'Primary Weapon
            Range("A17:C24").Interior.ColorIndex = 6 'Secondary Weapon
            Range("A8").Value = "" 'Primary Weapon
            Range("A17").Value = Application.VLookup(Range("B17"), ThisWorkbook.Names("dataWeaponField"), 2, False)
        Else
            Range("A8:C15").Interior.ColorIndex = 6 'Primary Weapon
            Range("A17:C24").Interior.ColorIndex = 12 'Secondary Weapon
            Range("A8").Value = Application.VLookup(Range("B8"), ThisWorkbook.Names("dataWeaponField"), 2, False)
            Range("A17").Value = "" 'Secondary Weapon
        End If
        Range("A6").Select 'Cell above CLICK TO SWAP WEAPONS
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you are passing a `Name` object instead of `Range`. You can set the Formula:

```
Range("A17").Formula = "=VLOOKUP(B17, dataWeaponField, 2, FALSE)"
```

or [Evaluate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Excel-VBA/articles/application-evaluate-method-excel) it:

```
Range("A17").Value = [VLOOKUP(B17, dataWeaponField, 2, FALSE)]
```

Also, because `SelectionChange` doesn't trigger when clicking a selected cell, you can use a Control or Hyperlink and the [Worksheet.FollowHyperlink Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Excel-VBA/articles/worksheet-followhyperlink-event-excel)

Comment: @chazcon it does the same as what you described in the question "This Excel formula in (for example) cell A17 works correctly: =VLOOKUP(B17,dataWeaponField,2,FALSE)"

Answer (score 0):

`ThisWorkbook.Names("dataWeaponField")` is a `Name` object, not a `Range` object. `VLookup` expects the latter, so you can simply replace this expression by `Application.Range("dataWeaponField")`.

The `Application.` prefix is necessary because your code is in a worksheet code module, and the named range belongs to another worksheet, so we need the application object to fetch it from global scope.

Alternatively you can evaluate the whole formula that works in Excel as is, using `Application.Evaluate(yourWorkingFormula)`.

Comment: The first solution results in an error: Run-time error '1004': Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed.

Comment: The second solution results in an error as well: Compile error: Sub or Function not defined.

Comment: @chazcon ah ok, because the code is in sheet code module. It should be `Application.Range("dataWeaponField")`, see edit.